# how to center a view in a constraint layout 1.0

Tags: android, center, android-constraintlayout, layout-gravity

I have a view (FrameLayout) in a constraintLayout

For tablet devices (only) I want to have this configuration

```
1) its max height to say 100dp 

2) It has to be wrap content 

3) It has to be centered in its parent (vertically and
horizontally).
```

I'm obligated to use constraint layout version 1.0

I have tried to use Top-Bottom to its parent constraints, but it's aligned to its parent's top.

I have tried to change       `app:layout_constraintHeight_default="wrap"` but making it       app:layout_constraintHeight_default="spread"` violates the wrap content requirement.

Here is my non-tablet layout, and I understand everything I want to make tablet only I would put under the `values-sw600dp` resources folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/popup_view_scrim_color"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:ignore="Overdraw">

  <FrameLayout
      android:id="@+id/viewToCenter"
      android:layout_width="300dp"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/account_menu_popover_top_margin"
      android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/account_menu_popover_bottom_margin"
      android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/account_menu_popover_side_margin"
      android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/account_menu_popover_side_margin"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintHeight_default="wrap"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0">
  </FrameLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

How can i fix this?

[image]

Comment: why is your `height==0dp`? `0dp` in `ConstraintLayout` means "match constraint". Have you tried using `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`?

Answer (score 2):

Since you want the view to be centered there is no need for all those margins:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/viewToCenter"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_default="wrap"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_max="100dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
</FrameLayout>
```

I added these attributes:

```
app:layout_constraintHeight_default="wrap"
app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap"
```

and changed to:

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
```